# Chrome Incognito Mode has a black theme, How to restore the grey one?

Tags: google-chrome

I tried chrome://flags/#top-chrome-md but I didn't get drop down menu with non-material design option.

How to get the normal theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this by editing settings in `chrome://flags`. Just type `chrome://flags` in the address bar and hit enter. Once on the flags page, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> if on Windows/Linux, or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> if on Mac and search for "Material Design in the browser's top chrome."

The default setting should be set to `default`. You can change the setting to `Non-material` to get the grey incognito look back.

Then click `Relaunch Chrome` located at the bottom of the screen after changing the setting.

Comment: My version is 55. I just find "Normal, Default, Touch" I tried all options here and they had nothing to do with black theme at incognito

Comment: @user2132188 I seem to be having the same problem. Are you on a Windows PC? When I wrote this answer I was on my MacBook, which has the options listed in my answer. On my Windows PC, I do not have the same options that I had on my MacBook. I'll have to double check the Chrome version that is on my Mac.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows 7 PC